# Java RandomAccessFile in Hadoop 2.8

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

I have installed Hadoop in my development machine in pseudo-distributed mode. So the default working directory is `/user/codeseeker`.

I'm trying to read a file from the working directory. If I use `HDFS`'s `FileSystem` with a `BufferedReader` , the file can be read. However, when I try to read it using `RandomAccessFile`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String loc = "storage/info.txt";
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(loc), conf);
    Path path = fs.getFileStatus(new Path(loc)).getPath(); 

    File file = new File(p.toUri().getPath()); 

    try {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        //
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

it throws a `FileNotFoundException`

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/codeseeker/storage/info.txt (No such file or directory)
```

How do I use it in Hadoop?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to use `FileSystem`. The file is not in a working directory, it is stored in hdfs.

Comment: `RandomAccessFile` doesn't accept a `FileSystem` object. Would you kindly link a resource that shows how to use `RandomAccessFile` in Hadoop?

Comment: I don't believe there is such a resource; the file is not stored on an edge node - your code goes to the data, not the other way around.